# How can this user have a negative year reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

How on earth did Noah Schweber (whose contributions to MathOverflow I always greatly enjoy) end up with a negative year [reputation for 2020](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/year/mathoverflow/2020-01-01/8133?sort=reputationchange#8133)?

[image]

Comment: There was a rep recalculation earlier this year (when questions and answers were revalued to be the same).  It could be that a bunch of Noah's posts had become community wiki in the interim, in which case this gets counted as negative reputation.  Not sure though, that seems like a lot of points to lose in one go.

Comment: I wonder if it's due to rewarding bounties.

Comment: You can expect similar results for other users who [often offer bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/962775/user-with-highest-amount-of-offered-bounties?num=100&min=50). Check, for example, the user [Ali Taghavi](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/year/mathoverflow/2020-01-01/36688?sort=reputationchange#36688).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They offered almost 4000 reputation in bounties so far this year:

https://mathoverflow.net/users/8133/noah-schweber?tab=bounties

Note that the -4827 is the decrease in *rank*, not in reputation, that's 'only' -129.

Comment: Maybe it is also worth mentioning that reputation for questions was changed from +5 to +10 in [November 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/). That meant that many users gathered a lot of reputation suddenly - and if they thought they don't need that much reputation, they might have used it for bounties. It seems that there was some increase to the amount of bounties [around beginning of 2020](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1284459/total-bounties-per-month#graph).

Comment: AFAICT in the reputation leagues the new (+10) reputation is still counted in the year when the question was posted. While the loss of reputation caused by the bounty is only recent.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I had the impression that when the question value was changed, stack exchange recalculated all reputation totals _including historical ones_. So that if you now look at, say, the [top reputation-getters of 2017](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/504/year/mathoverflow/2017-01-01), what you're seeing is what the reputation totals _would_ have been, _had_ the question upvote always been 10 rep. So I wouldn't think this change would lead to wonky reports of reputation _changes_, since those would all be calculated based on the fiction that question upvotes were always worth 10 rep.

Comment: I will add to @TimCampion's comment that my point was mainly that users with enough questions suddenly had more reputation available for bounties. (I probably wasn't clear enough in the above comments. I tried to explain myself a bit better [in the MO chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9369/conversation/change-to-10-for-questions-and-bounties).